# Bootstrap multi-select - Filtering issue with Group Labels

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Bootstrap (2.3.2)](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) multiselect in a Rails web application. The features I have used in multiselect are shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { 
    $('#coder_prod_select_client').multiselect({
      includeSelectAllOption: true,
      enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
      numberDisplayed: 0,
      nonSelectedText: 'Select Facility',
      maxHeight: 450
    });
  });
</script>
```

Below is the HTML Code:

```
<div id="coder_prod_facilities_for_select">
    <select name="facility[]" multiple="multiple" id="coder_prod_select_facility" style="display: none;">
        <option value="multiselect-all"> Select all</option>
        <optgroup label="Group 1">
            <option value="114">Ancillary</option>
            <option value="115">Inpatient</option>
            <option value="117">Emergency</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Group 2">
            <option value="80">Inpatient</option>
            <option value="81">SS Surgery</option>
            <option value="90">Emergency</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Group 3">
            <option value="73">Inpatient</option>
            <option value="75">Observation</option>
            <option value="76">SS Surgery</option>
            <option value="77">Ancillary</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>

    <div class="btn-group">
        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" type="button" title="Select Facility">
            Select Facility
            <b class="caret"></b>
        </button>
        <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu" style="max-height: 450px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control multiselect-search" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="multiselect-all">
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="multiselect-all">  Select all</label>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="display: list-item;">
                <label class="multiselect-group">Group 1</label>
            </li>
            <li style="display: list-item;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="114"> Ancillary</label>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="display: list-item;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="115"> Inpatient</label>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="display: list-item;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="117"> Emergency</label>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="display: list-item;">
                <label class="multiselect-group">Group 2</label>
            </li>
            <li style="display: list-item;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="80"> Inpatient</label>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="display: list-item;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="81"> SS Surgery</label>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="display: list-item;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="90"> Emergency</label>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="display: list-item;">
                <label class="multiselect-group">Group 3</label>
            </li>
            <li style="display: list-item;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="73"> Inpatient</label>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="display: list-item;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="75"> Observation</label>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="display: list-item;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="76"> SS Surgery</label>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="display: list-item;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="77"> Ancillary</label>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below you can see the view / HTML by default.
[image]

You could see there are similar elements under each group. For e.g, When I filter using the value 'inpatient', it is showing the result as shown in the below attachment.

[image]

But, each of the filtered 'Inpatient' values belong to separate Groups and all values should have been shown with it's group names on top!!, but it is not.

Could anyone please help me to identify and fix the issue?

Comment: Is it possible for you to try a different multi-select such as http://select2.github.io/select2/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the js again, shouldn't it be `$("#coder_prod_select_facility").multiselect(...)`?

Comment: No, only the mismatch id, it should be "coder_prod_select_facility" not "coder_prod_select_client"